# why it gets a syntax error in postgresql with command '''with as'''

Tags: postgresql

when I use ''' with  table1 as (select ...), table2 as(select ... ) select ...from table2''' in postgresql with dbmanager dbeaver ,a syntax error occured near the''',''' at '''tabl1 as(select ...),'''  ,why?

I have tried to delete the ''',''',but failed.
the error:org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ",

```
create table final_owner as
with data1 as (
  select fullnode as node, owner, address, block, logoffset, event_time 
  from registry_newowner 
),
data2 as (
  select node, owner, address, block, logoffet, event_time 
  from registry_transfer
),
combined_data as (
  select * from data1 
  union all 
  select * from data2
),
ranked_data as (
  select node ,owner, address, block, logoffset, event_time,
       row_number() over(partition by node order by event_time desc, block desc, logoffset desc)  as rn
  from combined_data
)
select node,owner, address, block, logoffset, event_time
from ranked_data
where rn=1;
```

Comment: I see no `tbl1` in the statement. Could you show the error message in more detail, as formatted text? Does the error come from PostgreSQL or from DBeaver?

Comment: `table1`, `tabl1`, `logoffet`, ... ? Please present a consistent question.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax looks ok. (Typos and obfuscated identifiers aside.) Maybe there is a problem with the SQL capabilities of your client.

Either way, you can simplify the query to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE final_owner AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (node) *
FROM  (
   SELECT node    , owner, address, block, logoffset, event_time
   FROM   registry_transfer
   UNION ALL
   SELECT fullnode, owner, address, block, logoffset, event_time
   FROM   registry_newowner
   ) sub
ORDER  BY node, event_time DESC, block DESC, logoffset DESC
```

That's typically faster, too. (And it removes the CTEs, which may have confused DBeaver.)

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)